# Div Contents are not showing up in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

This is my website [link](http://designmissionseries.com)

In chrome browser div contents are not showing up  if I do inspect element or window resize the contents are showing .But in Mozilla there is no issue everything is working fine.

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Your HTML code is commented somehow in Chrome.

Comment: Are you using some sort of CMS. Joomla maybe?

Comment: i m using html only @lonut

Comment: Simply linking to a website is considered bad practise, please either edit your question and include some code or this question will be closed.

Comment: i do not know where is the problem exactly i am not able to find out so only i asked you people..but you people are giving minus ratings to my question .no body is helping me out.@XO

Answer (score 0):

You have your code commented in Chrome because of some condition:

It appears like this when you inspect the page:

```html
<!--<div class="cat-wrapper" id="cat-portraits">

                    <div class="header animated" style="background-image:url(images/Gallery/portrait1.png)" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="200">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="title">
                            <p>P<br/>O<br/>R<br/>T<br/>R<br/>A<br/>I<br/>T<br/>S</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="images">

                        <div class="gallery-item animated regular" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait2.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img14.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated small" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait6.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img19.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated wide" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait9.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img13.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated wide" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait7.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img16.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated small" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait3.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img17.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated small" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait10.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img21.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated small" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait4.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img20.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated wide" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait8.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img18.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated small" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait11.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img3.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated regular" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait5.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img15.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item animated small" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400">
                            <img src="images/Gallery/portrait12.png" alt="">
                            <a href="images/Full_sizes/img22.jpg" class="overlay"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart-empty"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="icon1-heart"></a>
                            <p class="love">47</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>-->
```

Comment: @lonut : this is unwanted code which i do not want to display so i commented it..the actual code is enabled.